# UE4: Call a function from an another actor in parent class

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I currently have a problem because I can't figure out how to solve the problem. I have an actor that is supposed to call a function in the other actor on the "Begin Overlap Event".

The other actors that can trigger this event are all based on a parent blueprint in which the function was also implemented. My first idea was to cast directly to the parent BP. But that failed.

Maybe you can understand better what I mean with this little graphic.

[image: Graphic]

[image: Screenshot]

Do you have an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: You shouldn't need to do any casting. Is the function public?

Comment: @Ruzihm Yes, the function is set to Public, but I cannot simply call it because the target input cannot be populated with my actor because the editor says that this actor does not correspond to the class.

Answer (score 0):

you can't call function GetDamage() from the variable "Target" because it is AActor class - he doesn't know anything about a child's functionality.
if your overlapped actor ("OtherActor") is TowerBaseBP with the GetDamage then you absolutely can cast to it. You can do it until set "Target" (in this case need to change this variable from AActor to the TowerBaseBP), or cast until calling relevant function GetDamage().

1. check "OtherActor" on the ComponentBeginOverlap - Is it your child actor with the needed parent?
2. if so cast to the Parent class (not the child one) and set your "Target" variable (need to be Parent type);
3. then try to call GetDamage() from Target;
4. if you can't still call it, I have two suggestions:

- a) check your child classes - maybe you overrided GetDamage() and
  forgot to add CallToParent function;
- b) carefully check "OtherActor", and "Target" from  points 1-3;